# xml data display as NULL in database table. why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml-serialization, sqlxml

I am saving xml data into database table using below stored procedure but in the table values are disply NULL.

what is the prblem please help me.

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_readxmldata2]
(
@XMLdata XML
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @hDoc int

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT,@XMLdata

insert into xmlTable (Name, Value)
select xml.Name, xml.Value
from OPENXML(@hDoc,'/UpgradeLog/Properties/Property',1)
with(Name varchar(50) 'text()',
Value varchar(50) 'text()')xml

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Below is my XML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport.xslt'?><UpgradeLog>
<Properties>
<Property Name="Solution" Value="ecs_myecsinc">
</Property>
<Property Name="Solution File" Value="D:\Working Projects\ECSInc\ECSInc\ECSInc\ecs_myecsinc.sln">
</Property>
<Property Name="Date" Value="Wednesday, July 27, 2011">
</Property>
<Property Name="Time" Value="20:56 PM">
</Property>
</Properties>
<Event ErrorLevel="0" Project="" Source="ecs_myecsinc.sln" Description="File successfully backed up as D:\Working Projects\ECSInc\ECSInc\ECSInc\Backup\ecs_myecsinc.sln">
</Event>
<Event ErrorLevel="0" Project="" Source="ecs_myecsinc.sln" Description="Solution converted successfully">
</Event>
<Event ErrorLevel="3" Project="" Source="ecs_myecsinc.sln" Description="Converted">
</Event>
</UpgradeLog>
```

Comment: hard to say without your xml example, if you wanted to get attributes, try this `with(Name varchar(50) '@Name', Value varchar(50) '@Value')`

Comment: Hi Roman added XML file.

Answer (score 1):

```
select xml.Name, xml.Value
from OPENXML(@hDoc,'/UpgradeLog/Properties/Property',1)
with(
    Name varchar(50) '@Name',
    Value varchar(50) '@Value'
)
```

or your can select right from `@XMLData` using SQLXML:

```
select
    T.C.value('@Name', 'nvarchar(50)') as Name,
    T.C.value('@Value', 'nvarchar(50)') as Value
from @XMLdata.nodes('/UpgradeLog/Properties/Property') as T(C)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20025)</kbd>** with both solutions.